# How select data from table excluding data from second table Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

There is table **Log** where field **LogId** is **PK**.
Also there is table **userlog** with a fields: `userlogStatus`, `userlogIdLog`.

The relation across two table is: `Log.LogId = userlog.userlogIdLog`

How select rows from table `Log` excluding rows from `userlog,` if there are `userlogStatus = 1` ?
The expression `userlogStatus = 1` means that message from `Log` was read.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
 SELECT * from LOG
 inner join userlog on Log.LogId = userlog.userlogIdLog
 where userlogStatus <> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select l.*
from log l
where not exists (select 1 from userlog ul where l.LogId = ul.userlogIdLog and userLogStatus = 1);
```

For best performance, you would want an index on `userlog(userlogIdLog, userLogStatus)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT l.*
FROM Log l
LEFT JOIN userlog Log.LogId = userlog.userlogIdLog
WHERE userlogStatus is null or userlogStatus <> 1
```